# A universal function with a different slice types in argument

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a universal function that should compute a slice passed as an argument regardless of its type.
I have a few slices with a different types, but have no idea how to do this properly:

```golang
func SliceToChunks(arr []any, indices ...int) [][]any {
    collection := make([][]any, len(arr))

    n1 := indices[0]
    ...
    n6 := indices[5]

    collection = append(collection, arr[n1:n2])
    collection = append(collection, arr[n3:n4])
    collection = append(collection, arr[n5:n6])

    return collection
}

sliceA := []TypeA{1, 2, .. , 50}
sliceB := []TypeB{1, 2, .. , 50}

chunksA := SliceToChunks(sliceA, 5, 15)

// result should be:
//
// chunksA = [][]TypeA{
//  sliceA[ 0: 5],  5 pcs
//  sliceA[ 5:20], 15 pcs
//  sliceA[20:35], 15 pcs
//  sliceA[35:50], 15 pcs
// }

chunksB := SliceToChunks(sliceB, 20, 25)

// result should be:
//
// chunksB = [][]TypeB{
//  sliceB[ 0:20], 20 pcs
//  sliceB[20:45], 25 pcs
//  sliceB[45:50],  5 pcs (residue)
// }
```

I will be grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure if this is the best method as I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but give this a look.

```golang
func SliceToChunks[T any](arr []T, ranges [][2]int) [][]T {
    n := len(ranges)
    collection := make([][]T, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        collection[i] = arr[ranges[i][0]:ranges[i][1]]
    }

    return collection
}
```

Since you've initialized `collection` with a length (n), you don't have to use append, you can directly access the index.

Also, loop over the ranges for more concise code.

And finally, use Go's [generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics). I don't encourage using `T any`, you should union types or use something like `comparable`, as using `any` defeats the purpose of having a type system.

Comment: Note, generics were introduced in Go 1.18

Answer (score 0):

I believe You could use an interface{} generic type to achieve that:

```
func SliceToChunks(arr interface{}, indices ...int) interface{} {
    collection := make([]interface{}, len(indices)/2)

    for i := 0; i < len(indices); i += 2 {
        start := indices[i]
        end := indices[i+1]

        // Extract a sub-slice from arr and add it to the collection
        chunkValue := arrValue.Slice(start, end)
        collection[i/2] = chunkValue.Interface()
    }

    return collection
}
```